# Python mysql connector: Unread result found on an update

Tags: python, mysql-connector

excuse me for my English.
My problem is the following: I have the Unread result found error at the level of a simple update and I use an in-house framework of my company but here is the code that I can show:

```
python
 benef.salarie_id = beneficaire.salarie_id
                                benef.beneficiaire_pj = pj
                                benef.beneficiaire_ss = beneficaire.beneficiaire_ss
                                benef.beneficiaire_type = beneficaire.beneficiaire_type
                                benef.beneficiaire_noemie = beneficaire.beneficiaire_noemie
                                benef.beneficiaire_cv = beneficaire.beneficiaire_cv   
                                benef.update()
                                logging.info(
                                    'Mise à jour du bénéficiaire réussie')
```

All my script are object but basically I modify my object and then I call the update method, here is the method:

```
python
""Mise à jour d'un modèle dans la base de données.

  Args:
  column (Union[str, tuple], optional): La ou les colonnes à prendre en compte. Par défaut None.
clause (Union[Clause, tuple], optional): Le ou les types de clause. Par défaut Clause.EQUAL.
""
reflection = Reflection(self)
query = Query().update(reflection.getTable(), reflection.getColumns(), Reflection.generateMark(reflection.getValues()))
where, values = self.__findClause(column, clause)
self.__runOn(Query(f'{query} {where}'), reflection.getValues() + values, reflection)
logging.info('Mise à jour d\'un modèle dans la base de données.')
```

Then the __runOn method which allows Execute the Sql query

```
    def __runOn(self, query : Query, parameters : tuple = (), reflection : Reflection = None) -> Connection:
        """Exécute une requête sur la base de données liée au modèle.

        Args:
            query (Query): La requête à exécuter.
            parameters (tuple, optional): Les paramètres de la requête. Par défaut, la liste est vide.
            reflection (Reflection, optional): La réflexion existante du modèle. Par défaut None.
            
        Returns:
            Connection: La connexion à la base de données.
        """
        if reflection is None:
            reflection = Reflection(self)
        connection = Connection.getInstance(reflection.getDatabase())
        connection.runQuery(query, parameters)
        return connection
```

Then runQuery which executes sql queries

```
def runQuery(self, query : Query, parameters : Union[tuple, Any] = ()) -> 'Connection':
"""Exécute une requête SQL.

Args:
    query (Query): Objet de requête.
    parameters  (Union[tuple, Any], optional): Liste des paramètres de la requête. Par défaut, la liste est vide.

Returns:
    Connection: Instance de connexion à la base de données.
"""
logging.info(f'Exécution de la requête "{query}"...')
if type(parameters) is not tuple:
    parameters = (parameters,)
config = self.getConfigurations()
count = len(parameters)
hastimer = config.hasTimer()
sql = str(query)
start, stop = 0, 0
if count == 0 or type(parameters[0]) is not tuple:
    logging.info(f'Paramètres de la requête "{parameters}"...')
    if hastimer: start = time()
    self.__cursor.execute(sql, parameters)
    if hastimer: stop = time()
else:
    logging.info(f'Exécution multiple, paramètres non affichables...')
    size = config.getMaxpacket()
    lenght = round(size / len(parameters[0]))
    composites = [ parameters[x:x+lenght] for x in range(0, count, lenght) ]
    if hastimer: start = time()
    for composite in composites:
        self.__cursor.executemany(sql, composite)
        #faire un fetchall pour vider le buffer
        # self.__cursor.fetchall()
    if hastimer: stop = time()
logging.info(f'Exécution de la requête terminée.')
if hastimer:
    seconds = round(stop - start, 3)
    logging.info(f'Temps d\'exécution de la requête : {seconds} secondes.')
return self
```

I would like to understand why I have this error, thank you for your feedback

I've tried hard queries so without method nothing worked but the query works in my DBMS, I've tried to make this error non-blocking but then a select returns me the same error I would like to have a solution for this bug

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71717842/5320906) help?

Comment: Hi, Not that much because I already tried to add fetchone() on self.__cursor.fetchone() in the runQuery method after self.__cursor.execute(sql, parameters) but it tells me No result set to fetch from.

Comment: Is it possible that you are sharing connections between threads?

Comment: no there is only one connection is I do not share any thread at least to my knowledge